# Neural networks with a continuous function as the input

Tags: neural-networks, math, calculus

I am rethinking image recognition algorithms, and want to use an idea I saw in a 3Blue1Brown video:

The basic idea is to map pixels on an image to a specific frequency—every point is distinct—and if the pixel is brighter, make the amplitude of that sine curve larger.

And we could simply map the pixels to frequencies going row by row—how it’s done in traditional implementations—but why not strive for something better? We can use a Hilbert Curve to map the pixels to frequencies such that the frequency associated with a specific location change minimally if we scale up our resolution. [Full Video](https://youtu.be/3s7h2MHQtxc?si=p4Q8uOigPpnc_Z-T).

I was thinking of how this could extend to neural networks—and remembered how functions are just continuously infinite dimensional vectors. The input function here is the sum of frequencies with their respective amplitude.

So our first layer could be an infinite set of neurons, and the second layer could be a finite set of neurons. To connect these layers, we could have a series of functions (one for each neuron in the second layer).

To calculate the value of each neuron in the second layer, we could take the inner product with the input function (our image as a sum of sine curves) and a connecting function associated with this neuron.

Now, here’s where I’m having some trouble: how do we go about training such a network? Are there any gradient descent algorithms for such a neural network structure?

I was looking into the variational derivative, which we could potentially use in our gradient descent. But this seems to yield an analogue to a directional derivative—I’m not sure how to generalize this to a “variational gradient.”